# OpenCL or CUDA Which way to go?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, opencl

I'm investigating ways of using GPU in order to process streaming data. I had two choices but couldn't decide which way to go?

My criterias are as follows:

1. Ease of use (good API)
2. Community and Documentation
3. Performance
4. Future

I'll code in C and C++ under linux.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384930

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**OpenCL**

- interfaced from your production code
- portable between different graphics hardware
- limited operations but preprepared shortcuts

**CUDA**

- separate language (CUDA C)
- nVidia hardware only
- almost full control over the code (coding in a C-like language)
- lot of profiling and debugging tools

Bottom line -- OpenCL is portable, CUDA is nVidia only. However, being an independent language, CUDA is much more powerful and has a bunch of really good tools.

1. **Ease of use** -- OpenCL is easier to use out of the box, but once you setup the CUDA coding environment it's almost like coding in C.
2. **Community and Documentation** -- both have extensive documentation and examples, however I think CUDA has better.
3. **Performance** -- CUDA allows for greater control, hence can be better fine-tuned for higher performance.
4. **Future** -- hard to say really.

Comment: Actually there is one more advantage in using OpenCL, it can parallelize tasks in CPU too.

Comment: @holydiver, in this spirit you could say that neither Windows nor MacOS X has a bright future :>

Comment: @Kornel yes you are right, i didn't mentioned CPU and it is not a big issue for me :). I just point out that there is this feature that might be used as well. It may also be a good feature to use 1 API instead of using 2 seperate api's for CPU and GPU.

Comment: @Kornel After your answer, I'm more confused. Because i was likely leave out CUDA. But after I read the advantages of CUDA in your message, I stopped and started to think again :).

A main reason for me leaving out CUDA is even its installation in linux is somewhat problematic and you need to downgrade to gcc 4.3 in order to use it.

Comment: @Kornel absolutely, i don't see a very bright future for MacOSX and Windows and i hope they'll burn in hell :p

Comment: @holydiver: nonportable closed-source software will never go away.

Comment: Qt are making it easier to go openCL http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2010/04/07/using-opencl-with-qt/

Comment: You list the fact that CUDA has it's own C like language yet you fail to mention the OpenCL C like language that is used to write OpenCL kernels.

Answer (score 18):

My personal experiences were:

1. API: OpenCL has slightly more complex api. However most time you will spent with writing kernel code, and here both are almost identical.
2. Community: CUDA has a much bigger community then OpenCL up til now, but this will probably about to even out.
3. Documentation: Both are very well documented.
4. Performance: We made the experience, that OpenCL drivers are not yet fully optimized.
5. Future: The future lies with OpenCL as it is an open standard, not restricted to a vendor or specific hardware!

This assessment is from 2010, so probably out-dated.

Answer (score 6):

OpenCL all the way unless you have a specific reason to use CUDA. OpenCL runs well on multicores like Intel i7 in addition to running on GPUs. By using OpenCL you can run it on a much wider range of hardware from Droid cell phones to the IBM Power7 compute nodes of the world's largest supercomputer, [Blue Waters](http://www.ncsa.illinois.edu/BlueWaters/), which is supposed to come online next year.