# CUDA or OpenCL for OpenGL integration?

Tags: opengl, cuda, opencl

I wanna know what do you prefer to choose for an OpenGL integration. Some time ago, I read that OpenCL had an optimal integration with OpenGL, because of they belong to the same company, but I also read that CUDA has got a very good performance with using NVIDIA's graphics cards. So, If I have got a NVIDIA card, and I want to develop with graphics, what should I choose? OpenCL or CUDA?

Can you give the benefits of the using of OpenCL + OpenGL, and disadvantages of CUDA + OpenGL or vice versa?

Remember, we're working with NVIDIA's platform.

Answer (score 2):

opencl and opengl technically are standards maintained by khronos groups, khronos group is made from several companies representative .
i don't know if nvidia is optimizing its cuda implementation more than its own opencl implementation but  Nvidia has opencl  for its cards and of course and  you can use either opencl or cuda for your device. 
if you are learning CUDA / OPENCL from the beginning i would go for opencl ( because it follows a standard implemented by multiple company and NVIDIA implements it as well ).
but if you already know CUDA, just go ahead and implement your code and get your project going and later on worry about cross platforms issues.

and this posts has everything 
[OpenCL or CUDA Which way to go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644979/opencl-or-cuda-which-way-to-go)